# Jquery UI Droppable on image map

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I have an image map defined as below

```
  <img src="../../Content/Images/Mapimage.png"  usemap="#Map" />
        <map name="Map">
            <area id="s1" shape="rect" coords="200,45,270,105"/>
            <area id="s2" shape="rect" coords="215,275,280,335"/>
            <area id="s3" shape="rect" coords="110,270,180,335"/>
        </map>
```

and a draggable image

```
 <img src="../../Content/Images/image1.png" id="draggableImage"/>
```

and the jquery

```
      $("#draggableImage").draggable({
        helper: 'clone',
        appendTo: 'body',

    });

     $("#s1").droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            alert("Got it");
        }
    });
```

when I drag and drop nothing happens.
If I drag and drop to a div that I have set as droppable that is NOT in an image map it works. It is just not working when I drop on an image map area.
Any thoughts how to do this on an image map area?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle example?